# How to make padding-left match margin: auto of other element

Tags: html, css, alignment

[image: Padding and margin matching]

I have the title of a page displayed in an orange box at bottom of header (see image above). This box currently has padding-left set to 15% which makes it match the margin-left of the text below only if the window width is right. But if the window size changes they no longer match (see image below).

[image: Padding and margin not matching.]

I want the text to be aligned left in all window sizes. I did try "padding: 0 calc(50% - 540px);" for the title but that only works as long as the width of the containers are 1080px or wider. More importantly it doesn't seem to work in Microsoft Edge which is necessary.

Any suggestions on how to do this? Is it possible without changing the structure of my elements?

Comment: Change the with of the title to match with the content, set margin to auto. The radiant background can be set with pseudo elements or simply wrapped the title in another div.

Comment: Yes it seems like that's the only way to do what I want. Was hoping it could be solved without altering the html but no luck there it seems.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you used bootstrap if you want your page to be responsive.

There is Bootstrap Spacing https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion I'm not sure I can use it for our site but I'll take a look at it. I would have preferred a solution using just css if possible.

Comment: Why don't you use the same padding size for the same box but use a % because its responsive example #box, #box2 {padding:20%;}